# Is it effective to use object with bulkey methods to pass properties?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to OOP so this may be a dumb question to ask..

When I create a class (C#, ASP.NET) with properties and LARGE NUMBER OF METHODS in it, if i create an object of it just to pass from one layer to another (like from Presentation to Business Logic) isn't it a overhead to pass the object with large number of methods?

Please explain how this is normally achived??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead of passing an object does not depend on the number of methods.

There is a cost associated with passing around value types with many **fields** (`struct`s in C#), maybe you are confused with that.

Comment: Does it mean when I create an object (to pass between layers), it'll not create an object in memory with all methods (code) complied in to it?

Comment: That's correct. All the method implementations are in memory only once, for all objects of the same type. The runtime knows which method can be called on what type of object. As for `virtual` functions, there is a single table of function pointers shared for all objects of the same type. This is true for most statically typed languages like Java C++.

Answer (score 2):

The overhead doesn't depends on the number of methods but it comes from the number of passed parameters between methods

check this [post](http://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization) it may help you to optimize your code

Answer (score 2):

Class is a [Reference-Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), therefore don't worry about passing parameters, it does not depend on the number of methods.